# More angle measure in a circle

Tags: geometry

Given: measurement of arc AB=x 
Prove: measurement of angle 1=180-×,  I don't know how to prove this one because I know that to find the angle measures I have to subtract both arcs and dive it by to to get the measure of angle one so I don't understand it at all help please! [image]

Comment: Let $O$ be the center of the circle. Then the angles $OAC$ and $OBC$ are both $90º$ and $BOA=x$. Can you conclude from here?

Comment: @u1571372, Angles $OAC$ and $OBC$ can not be $90°$ unless $CA$ and $CB$ are tangent to the circle, something which is not mentioned in the question. And also how do you say $BOA=x$?

Comment: @Edith Mendoza, Are those $CA$ and $CB$ tangents to the circle?

Comment: Yes those are tangents to the circle

Comment: @EdithMendoza, Then the problem is clear now.

Answer (score 1):

Tangents to a circle are perpendicular to the radius at the point point of tangency.
[image]